# Выравнять элементы списка по ширине

Tags: css

[На этой странице](http://darsa.in/sly/examples/vertical.html) под слайдером есть список (точечки - переключатели по слайдам). Он сейчас выровнен по центру, а как сделать, чтобы было по ширине, чтобы точечки располагались на равном расстоянии друг от друга, независимо от того, сколько элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@unfapable](/users/13114/unfapable)](/users/13114/unfapable), кроссбраузерное решение есть:

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/fzb0vj2p/)**

Все это реализуется с помощью `text-align: justify;`.
Поддержка IE начиная с 8-й версии.

Если заменить псевдоэлемент на дополнительный `li`, то поддержка IE с 7-й версии будет, думаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: А есть кроссбраузерное решение?

Comment: Да, конечно. К этому же коду нужно добавить вендорные префиксы.

Comment: Я имел в виду прежде всего ИЕ. Как с ним?

Comment: IE? По крайней мере в тех, которые входят в десятку самых популярных браузеров, точно всё хорошо. В тех, доля которых превышает два процента - тоже всё замечательно.